# cURL on AWS Lambda gives command not found error

Tags: curl, aws-lambda

Starting a few hours today, a simple curl command on Lambda is failing. 
Lambda environment is NodeJs 10.x (have also tried in 12.x).

```
const { execSync } = require('child_process');

exports.handler = async (event) => {
   execSync('curl http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/images/BigBuckBunny.jpg -o /tmp/BigBuckBunny.jpg');
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };
    return response;
};
```

I get a /bin/sh curl: command not found error
Any idea what the issue is?

```
Response:
{
  "errorType": "Error",
  "errorMessage": "Command failed: curl http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/images/BigBuckBunny.jpg -o /tmBigBuckBunny.jpg\n/bin/sh: curl: command not found\n",
  "trace": [
    "Error: Command failed: curl http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/images/BigBuckBunny.jpg -o /tmBigBuckBunny.jpg",
    "/bin/sh: curl: command not found",
    "",
    "    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:621:11)",
    "    at execSync (child_process.js:657:15)",
    "    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:11:4)",
    "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"
  ]
}
```

Comment: :) Thanks. Just that this is on AWS Lambda where it was working earlier.

Comment: Oops, AWS does confuse things, but still it just means your `$PATH` variable isn't set the way it should be. Maybe you can add `/usr/bin/curl` to the cmd? (or the correct full path)? Removing previous comment. Good luck. (as always ;-) ) .

Comment: Has curl been removed or moved to a new location in Lambda? /usr/bin does not have curl.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally i have a confirmation from Amazon support (and their internal tech team) that CURL binary is no longer included as part of the AWS Lambda environment based on Amazon Linux 2. Which is why I am not able to perform curl using either execSync or spawnSync in Node 10 and Node 12.

The alternative as per them is to use the "requests" library https://github.com/request/request/blob/master/README.md#streaming

Answer (score 2):

I tried using spawnSync instead of execSync and it's working.

const {spawnSync} = require('child_process');

The `spawnSync` uses a process environment to run your command, while an `execSync` uses a shell environment.The curl path is apparently not configured in the shell environment.

Comment: So as per AWS support: AWS Node.js 10.x uses the Amazon Linux 2 and Node.js used Amazon Linux hence the difference in shared libraries and that explains the error because some libraries are installed in a different path directory for new runtime environment. As per them spawnSync is the way to go so I am marking this as correct for other users to see, however spawnsSync did not resolve my issue of download.