# Openssl on lambda with Nodejs10 in Amazon linux 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, openssl, amazon-linux-2

Amazon Linux 2 lambda

I can’t execute OpenSSL with console call in lambda with node10.x runtime. AWS will leave the support for node8.10 and I have a platform serverless that use OpenSSL with console call with node8.10

My code was some similar to next

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // TODO implement
    var queryOpenssl = "echo gatos | openssl base64"
    exec(queryOpenssl, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        var flgError = !!error
        var flgStdout = !!stdout
        var flgStderr = !!stderr
        console.log("flgError", flgError)
        console.log("flgStdout", flgStdout)
        console.log("flgStderr", flgStderr)
        console.log("stdout : ", stdout)
        console.log("error : ", error)
        console.log("stderr : ", stderr)
        const response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
        };
        return response;
    })
};
```

And the response always was `command not found: openssl`

I did the next tests

1. Search openssl with `which openssl` but it wasn´t successful.
2. Search openssl with `find / openssl` but Amazon Linux 2 isn´t has this command.
3. Search openssl navigated for some directories without success.

Comment: I believe this answer may be able to help you Luis: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59166043/3968358. In that answer cURL gives command not found (same for openssl in your case). So you have 2 options: 1) use native binary package in AWS Lambda or 2) use nodejs request or http built-in module. Lambda creates a container on top of a VM to run your code, so it's not like running application code on a normal host.

Comment: Tks! I got binary of a EC2 with Amazon Linux 2. Copied binary in a layer and I set environment variable PATH

It’s work

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem.

I had to get the binary from EC2 with Amazon Linux 2
1. Wake up EC2 `ami-00068cd7555f543d5 (64-bit x86) / ami-035240afa793cddbb`[Take this AMI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFs3J.png)
2. Open ssl connection at EC2 and execute `whereis openssl` and you will get this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yyf8.jpg)
3. You locate path of openssl
4. In your machine you should execute next command `scp -i file.pem ec2-user@.......com:/usr/bin/openssl ./` for to get openssl binary
5. You should make a [layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) for your lambda functions and set `ENVIRONMENT VARIALE` PATH with this value `/var/lang/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/:/bin:/opt/bin:/opt/lib` , whit this, you will override PATH of Amazon Linux 2 and it will take the binaries in /opt/lib route where is openssl of layer.

Comment: Not working this, The binary is just one file I created zip file and uploaded at AWS Lambda layer. Updated PATH to use openssl but still Lambda function didn't recognized those binary file... any help?

Comment: sure, What is your stack ?

Comment: Any chance you could share the ARN for your layer?