# Different results for request in AWS Lambda and in local or other AWS VMs

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm performing some tests to learn how to effectively perform web scrapping.
I have developed some scripts in my local Python environment that are working fine:

```py
    ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
    header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) '
                            'AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                            'Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
              'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
              'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
              'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
              'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
              'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
   req = urllib.request.Request(url=url_page, headers=header) 
   page = urllib.request.urlopen(req) # If timeout is addded, entire execution is
   soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser', multi_valued_attributes=None)
   return soup
```

But, when the same code is deployed in AWS Lamba (same libraries, same environment), the result is different because the HTML of the page that I'm trying to scrap is not complete (The section that I wanted to scrap is gone).

I have tried performing a simple curl from my local environment too and I'm able to get the full web page (using previous headers), but when I try to only download the page HTML from AWS Lambda ([as cURL is no longer available in Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58956951/curl-on-aws-lambda-gives-command-not-found-error)):

```py
 page = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
 file_test = "/tmp/test1.html"
 with open(file_test, "w") as file1:
     file1.write(str(page.read()))
 client = s3_management.get_s3_client()
 client.upload_file(file_test, "bucket", file_test)
```

I get a HTML version that is not complete.

In my desperation, **I have also tried using aiohttp library (with asyncio) instead of urlib.request in order to implement an asynchronous request, but the result was the same**: an incomplete HTML page and a different version than the one that I was able to see when I execute the code in my local environment.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Like a kind of witchcraft, and with pretty clear resembles to what is described in the book *[Pragmatic thinker](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3063393-pragmatic-thinking-and-learning)*, I had a "[L-mode to R-mode](https://toolshed.com/articles/2015-01-29-LRModeDMN.html)" moment meanwhile I was writing the question.

**I was using eu-west-3 (Paris) region in my Lambda function. I  changed it to us-west-2 (Oregon) and the code executed in Lambda started to return the expected results and not an incomplete version of the HTML scrapped.**